# What is the output of the following line of code?

Tags: java

What is the output of the following lines of code? (JAVA)

```
int nums[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};

System.out.println(nums[1]+nums[3]);
```

I'm doing a practise revision sheet but I can't seem to workout the answer to this. EITHER - 7, 4, 5 OR 6.

ALSO when i try to put it into my Eclipse, it doesn't work.

Comment: SO is not a substitute for a compiler or basic Java comprehension.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  What do you think it should be, and why?  Add that to your question, and we can point out where your error may be.  Or post what you put in Eclipse and we can point to why it didn’t work for you.  We can’t learn for you.  If we say the answer is (say) `7`, and you accept it without question, you aren’t learning.

Comment: Also, for future reference, "it doesn't work" is rather unhelpful.  We don't know if that means a compiler error, a runtime error, no error but the program doesn't run, Eclipse crashes, or your computer starts on fire.  Give us the error message.

Answer (score 0):

The above code is first declaring an array of integer and then adding the second element (as in programming counting starts from zero), and 4 the element of the array.
If you want to run it on eclipse try this :

`

```
class Aartest
{
 public static void main(String[] atg)
{
 int nums[] = {1,32,1,2,31};
 System.out.println(nums[1]+nums[3]);
}
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

The first line declares an array of integers. An array is a data structure which can hold more than 1 value at a time. To access the values you use indexes. The indexes start from 0. To access a value you write the array name followed by the index of the element in square brackets:

```
arrayName[index];
```

Index 0 gives you the first value in the array, index 1 - the second, and so on.

`nums[1]` will give you the second element in the array - 2.
`nums[3]` will give you the fourth element in the array - 4.
The second line will print the sum of `nums[1]` amd `nums[3]` which is 2 + 4 = 6.